# Continua ainda "add a comment" sem tradução?

Tags: bug, status-pronto, internacionalização

Sobre a pergunta: [Adicionar comentário não está traduzido](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1752/11549), não obtivemos nenhum esclarecimento. Como podemos ter alguma providência sobre o assunto?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Maria, essas correções dependem do Gabe, nosso gerente de comunidade, pedir aos desenvolvedores do site que acrescentem uma nova chave no sistema de tradução. Isso feito, ele (e só ele) pode corrigir. Toda semana ele tem reunião com os devs e leva esses assuntos, então tudo que podemos fazer é deixar o bug registrado aqui no meta e esperar.

Comment: Ok, @bfavaretto, obrigada pela resposta!

Comment: @bfavaretto faltou status-pronto na oringinal dessa duplicada

Comment: Viu, não sou só eu que estou ajudando o Gabe :) @Math